# How to embed native dependencies of a DLL with Costura?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, fody-costura

I want to distribute my app as a single `.exe` file.

For that, I am using `Costura.Fody` to embed the dependencies of my app. However, the dependecy itself has native dependencies (`PdfiumViewer` NUGet package). Originally, these resided in the `x86`/`x64` folders, but I moved them to `costura32`/`costura64` respectively and set them as `Embedded resource`.

When I build the project, the *Output* tab displays that the `PdfiumViewer.dll` has been embedded. But when I run the program, there's an exception from `PdfiumViewer.NativeMethods`.

Can I achieve a single `.exe` file ? (I am on `.NET 3.5`)

---

Since the native depencies have the same name (`pdfium.dll`) I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744702/how-to-embed-32-64bit-dlls-with-same-name-in-a-mixed-mode-exe) is related.

Comment: It seems to be on track for the next release: https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/85